# Detaching, manipulating, appending

Tags: jquery

I was reading [jqFundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/book/index.html) this weekend, and Rebecca Murphey talks about:

> The $.fn.detach method is extremely
>   valuable if you are doing heavy
>   manipulation to an element. In that
>   case, it's beneficial to $.fn.detach
>   the element from the page, work on it
>   in your code, and then restore it to
>   the page when you're done.

I have a table sort like this, which I got from "Learning jQuery", page 140:

```
var rows = $table.find('tr:not(:has(th))').get();
rows.sort(function(rowA,rowB) {
...
});
$.each(rows, function(index,row) {
  $table.children('tbody').append(row);
});
```

I wonder if I should detach the table and reattach it?

Comment: how many row's are you dealing with ?

Comment: The idea behind detach is similar to a screen buffering in games. Any change you do on an element is visible on the screen (consuming browser resources). If you don't care about the user seeing every change done, only the final result, you could use detach safely.

Comment: The title of this question doesn't seem to go too well with the actual content ...

Comment: Oh!  I'm sorry!  I started asking a question, exited my browser and when I came back in the subject line was still there.  Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detaching an element removes it from the DOM.  So, if you were to detach the the table element, the whole table would likely disappear or "flash" until you re-insert the table back into the DOM.

However, you may want to detach only the `tbody` element from the DOM and then reinsert it into the table when you are done sorting the rows.

Comment: var $parent = $table.parent();
$table.detach();
$parent.append($table);

Comment: No flashing should occur as long as you stay in the same execution thread. It may flash if you yield back to the browser by calling an asynchronous function though.